# Number of Inversions in Merge Sort python

Tags: python, algorithm, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to count the number of inversions inside a Merge Sort algorithm. I have not made many modifications except adding a counter for the condition to flip the values if the value on the right hand is smaller than the left. The code I am using is below and it even prints the right answer on pythontutor.com but also generates an error. What I am not able to understand is the source of the error. Will someone here be able to please explain what am i not seeing? My code is below along with the error:

```
def merge(left,right):
    result=[]
    i,j=0,0
    count=0
    while (i<len(left)) and (j<len(right)):
      if left[i]<right[j]:
          result.append(left[i])
          count+=1
          i+=1
      else:
          result.append(right[j])
          j+=1

    while (i<len(left)):
      result.append(left[i])
      i+=1

    while (j<len(right)):
      result.append(right[j])
      j+=1
   # print(count)
 return result,count

def merge_sort(list):
    if len(list)<2:
        return list
    else:
        middle=len(list)//2
        left=merge_sort(list[:middle])
        right=merge_sort(list[middle:])
        # return merge(left,right)
        result,count=merge(left,right)
        print(result,count)

merge_sort([2,3,9,2,9])
```

The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: I think the indentation is wrong. Perhaps something is wrong during copying.

Comment: Yea, the indentation is not the issue. Stackoverflow is just not letting me indent the code while copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is in the `else` block of your `merge_sort` function-  you never return your list, so Python implicitly returns `None`. You want something like:

```py
left,   left_count  = merge_sort(list[:middle])
right,  right_count = merge_sort(list[middle:])
result, merge_count = merge(left, right)

count = left_count + right_count + merge_count
return result, count
```

Aside: You shouldn't use builtin types (e.g. "list") as variable names, since they shadow the actual type.

Comment: My end goal is to count the number of inversions. Returning result will definitely give me a sorted array but not the number of inversions. And that is where I am stuck.

Comment: Right. The same concept applies- you need to return both then. Right now you return nothing, so your recursive calls return `None`, giving the exception.

Comment: Dude, I don't know how to thank you. You are a life saver. I was literally stuck on this problem for the past 3 days and for some reason could not see the mistake. I do see it now.

Comment: @HaseebKhan Glad to hear that it makes sense now. If this resolves your question, you may want to accept the answer to make it clear that the question is no longer open